# DropdownlistFor not disabling when used with chosen jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen jquery plugin for my dropdownlist .I need to disable the dropdown in respect to certain condition.But dropdown is not gettin disabled.`

This is my jquery.

```
    if (($('#ID').val() != "") && ($('#ID').val() != -9999999)) {

        $('#ID').prop("disabled", true);
    }
```

My Dropdownlist

```
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.Department, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentCode"), "-- Select Department--", new { @class = "chosen-select", id = "ID" })
```

Comment: i tried with $('#ID').attr("disabled", true); but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/67) the Chosen jQuery Plugin only checks the dropdown for the `disabled` status when you initially build it. i.e. when you call `.chosen();`.

To get around this you have to trigger the `chosen:updated` event so that the plugin can modify itself based on changes made to the underlying Select element.

Here is a quote from the [Documentation page](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) :

> chosen:updated
>
> This event should be triggered
>   whenever Chosen's underlying select element changes (such as a change
>   in selected options).

And here is the example jQuery Code :

```
$('#ID').prop("disabled", true);
$('#ID').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

This code will disable the underlying select and then force the Chosen Plugin to refresh.

Comment: @Nunners, even i missed it. Believe me a worked a lot with chosen jquery plugin. Am feeling dumb nw.

Comment: Cheer Up !! Thats why we have StackOverflow !! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the attribute incorrectly.

```
$('#ID').prop("disabled", false) //this will set the disabled attribute to false which means enable is true
```

Try this:

```
$('#ID').prop("disabled", true);
```

Or if prop function is not working for you then you can use the attr function ie:

```
$('#ID').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Sry! i tried with true ,it dint work so i tried with false ! I have corrected my question :P

Comment: Try this : $('#ID').attr("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: @FurquanKhan I think you seem to be missing the point, it's not that the Dropdown object itself is not disabled, it's that the [Chosen jQuery Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) isn't disabled.